# Shell program to just open a character driver and wait

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

What inspired this question is that I am testing the functionality of watchdog device and I was thinking if there is a shell inbuilt command to just open the device and do nothing/wait until terminated?
`Echo/touch` seem to just open and close the device immediately after performing the operation. `Cat` does not seem to work.

I am using a C application to do the same but was wondering if shell script has some provision for it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Bourne-like shells,

```
exec 3< "$device"
```

Opens the device on file descriptor 3 of the shell.

That would be more or less equivalent to C's:

```
fd = open(device, O_RDONLY);
if (fd < 0) handler_error(...);
if (fd != 3) { dup2(fd, 3); close(fd); }
```

(`ksh93` also does a `fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)` on that fd).

To close it: `exec 3<&-`

In `zsh`, `ksh93` and `bash`, the equivalent of `fd = open(device, O_RDONLY)` could also be written as:

```
exec {fd}< "$device"
```

Where the file descriptor would be the first free one above 9 and stored in `$fd`.

To close it: `exec {fd}<&-`

Replace `<` with `>` for `O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC`, and with `<>` for `O_RDWR|O_CREAT` and `>>` for `O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND`.

`zsh` also has a [`sysopen` builtin (in the `zsh/system` module)](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-sysopen) where you can specify the flags exactly.

Note that in POSIX compliant shells, `exec` being a *special builtin*, if the file can't be opened, it's a fatal error when non-interactive (it exits the script). You can disabled that by using the `command` command.

```
if command exec 3< "$device"; then
  do-what-you-need-to-do
else
  handle-the-error-yourself
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while sleep 3600; do :; done >/dev/your_watchdog
```

I gather (from the `echo` and `touch` working and the `cat` failing) that the device should be open in write only mode.

Comment: `sleep 1e99 >/dev/your_watchdog` would also work, assuming you're not planning on being after 10 to the 91 years or so...

Comment: `sleep: invalid number '1e99'` ;-)